# Differentiating Azure SDK Namespaces Microsoft.Azure.Management and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management

Tags: azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

We have 2 namespaces as part of Azure SDK i.e.  Microsoft.Azure.Management and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management. 
1. How do we differentiate or which one to use when?
2. Is Microsoft.Azure.Management won't support all services?
3. I could able to create a classic storage account using  Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management and so is it only supports classic and not supports to create a storage account under a Resource Group?

Any light here would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. How do we differentiate or which one to use when?

As far as I know, the [Microsoft.Azure.Management](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage) is used to create the new arm azure resources.

The [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries/)(you could see the last updated date is   2014/9/16) is used created the classic asm resources.

The difference between arm and asm, you could refer to this [article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meamcs/2016/12/22/difference-between-azure-service-manager-and-azure-resource-manager/).

I suggest you could choose Microsoft.Azure.Management to create new arm resources in azure. Like web app, VM and so on.

Because, multiple service now only support arm(e.g web app).

> 2. Is Microsoft.Azure.Management won't support all services?

Not all services is supported in Microsoft.Azure.Management, but it is still updating.

About the library supported service, you could refer to [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/psSdkJson6/Documentation/sdk-for-net-packages.md).

> I could able to create a classic storage account using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management and so is it only supports classic and not supports to create a storage account under a Resource Group?

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management doesn't support created the storage account under a resource group.

Comment: Thanks for these valuable Ref. I finally decided to go with Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluid, which is more programmer friendly.